# Flutter Stream List Filter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app that searches for specific bluetooth devices.  I am using FlutterBlue and so my code looks like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
    stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults
```

The problem is that I want to filter out the results based on some criteria.  `scanResults` is type `Stream<List<ScanResult>>` and with a normal `List` I would do `.where((element) => true/false)` but when I do `.where` the `element` is actually type `List` instead of the `ScanResult` which doesn't make sense.

Can't figure out how I am supposed to do this.  I've searched around to no avail.  I must be missing a setup to maintain the Stream but be able to rebuild the list based on a `.where`

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-async/Stream/where.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter on the list you need to filter on the snapshot data provided in the `StreamBuilder` builder directly.

Here is a small example:

```dart
StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
  stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return LoadingWidget()
    }

    final filteredResult = snapshot.data!.where((element) => ...);
  },
);
```